# Unable to use related field in domain filter

Tags: odoo-8, odoo-view

Field declaration in odoo v8, `team_manager` is a new class:

```
class team_manager(osv.osv):
    _name = "team.manager"

    _columns = {
        'is_manager': fields.related('manager_id', 'manager', type='boolean', relation="hr.employee", string='Managers', readonly=True, store=True)
    }
```

The xml file code for `'Form View'`

```
<separator string="Team Work" attrs="{'invisible':[('is_manager','=',False)]}"/>
<field name="child_line" context="{'manager_id':id}" attrs="{'invisible':[('is_manager','=',False)]}">
    <tree editable="=top">
        <field name="employee_id"/>...
    </tree>
</field>
```

While opening the form I am getting the error like

```
    Odoo Client Error

    Error: Unknown field is_manager in domain [["is_manager","=",false]]

    http://localhost:8069/web/static/src/js/view_form.js:1702
```

Can't we use related filed in domain? or Does my syntax need changes?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `is_manager` field to the form view.
Add the following line before `child_line` field:

```
<field name="is_manager" invisible="True"/>
```